# react native transition animation for navigator.replace()

Tags: react-native

I'm working on a navigation that there's no more than one route in the stack.

So I'm using replace() instead of the pop() and push(). But the problem I noticed is that while using replace(), there isn't a transition animation available such as the one I see with pop() and push().

Is there a way to get around that? Or is there other ways to implement a navigation with one view replacing an existing one (with transition animation of course)?

Comment: Found any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having the same issue and managed to find the solution [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1981#issuecomment-223568264) provided by zhaotai.

To solve the issue, define the following new method in the js file where you import the Navigator component.

```
Navigator.prototype.replaceWithAnimation = function (route) {
  const activeLength = this.state.presentedIndex + 1;
  const activeStack = this.state.routeStack.slice(0, activeLength);
  const activeAnimationConfigStack = this.state.sceneConfigStack.slice(0, activeLength);
  const nextStack = activeStack.concat([route]);
  const destIndex = nextStack.length - 1;
  const nextSceneConfig = this.props.configureScene(route, nextStack);
  const nextAnimationConfigStack = activeAnimationConfigStack.concat([nextSceneConfig]);

  const replacedStack = activeStack.slice(0, activeLength - 1).concat([route]);
  this._emitWillFocus(nextStack[destIndex]);
  this.setState({
    routeStack: nextStack,
    sceneConfigStack: nextAnimationConfigStack,
  }, () => {
    this._enableScene(destIndex);
    this._transitionTo(destIndex, nextSceneConfig.defaultTransitionVelocity, null, () => {
      this.immediatelyResetRouteStack(replacedStack);
    });
  });
};
```

Then, you can call `navigator.replaceWithAnimation(route)` instead.

Comment: Hello. Could you point me where to insert this code ? I'm new and I don't know where's the Navigator come from. Thank you

Comment: @boygiandi `Navigator` was deprecated since 0.44. You can refer [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/navigation) on how to navigate between screens for 0.62 (current version).